# Sprite Kit sprite creation not working on 64 bit simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a sprite kit application that I have thoroughly tested on my 32 bit devices. I recently found out that my app crashes on startup when run on a 64 bit device.

This code is in my `init` method for a class that inherits from an `SKNode`.

```
self.sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[_properties objectForKey:@"Sprite"]];

[self.sprite setScale:BUILDING_SCALE];

[self addChild:_sprite];
```

The app crashes at the `addChild` line only on the 64 bit simulator.

I tried printing out the description of `self.sprite` on the **32 bit** simulator:

```
<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'image1.png' (266 x 76)] position:{0, 0} size:{53.200001, 15.2} rotation:0.00
```

and again on the **64 bit** simulator:

```
<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:['nil'] position:{0, 0} size:{53.200000762939453, 15.199999809265137} rotation:0.00
```

Another strange thing, is that if I put a breakpoint on the line where the sprite is first initialized and step over, the sprite is valid.

Any ideas?

Call stack:
[image]

Comment: what type of crash? anything in the log, ie error message? What's the call stack?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x30). I'll add a screenshot of the call stack. Nothing in the console.

Comment: add an exception breakpoint and verify that the above code is the actual addChild call that crashes. And check what _properties returns for the sprite key.

Comment: I have an exception breakpoint. It stops at the addChild. The _properties returns the correct image file name.

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project as well as removing the app from device/simulator?

Comment: Yeah, makes no difference. I've tried removing the code and found that it crashed in a different place, again when I try to add a sprite.

Comment: I have found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this happens only on 64 bit, but the problem was that the sprite property was `assign` instead of `strong`.

Functional:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *sprite;
```

Crash:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) SKSpriteNode *sprite;
```

Comment: Of course. The assign property keyword is equivalent to __unsafe_unretained allowing the sprite to be "garbage collected" and the sprite property left with a dangling pointer. It could probably have crashed in 32-bit too but didn't because maybe the compiler generates slightly different ARC code for 32 and 64 bit.